# Connect without object

Tags: c++, qt

I want to connect some function as slot without class, can I do this:

```
void update() { }

int main()
{
  QTimer timer = ...;
  QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(update()));
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler says, that without object it's impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you can only connect signals to slots, and slots can only exist as member functions of a Q_OBJECT.

While many people focus on the template vs. moc difference between Qt signals and boost::signals or GTKmm signals, THIS is the difference I ultimately care more about.  Qt's signals are not as expressive and cause more dependencies than I want.

I still use Qt, but that's just because GTKmm accessibility is completely missing on win32 systems.

What you can do, of course, is make a subclass of QTimer that connects to its own timeout signal with a slot that generates a boost::signal that you CAN connect to your external function.  Take care of the issues in using boost signals in Qt though, I just use signals2 to avoid it entirely AND I get thread safety.

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that this functionality is being introduced in Qt 5. http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Answer (score 1):

You need that Qt recognize the slot. To do so, you have to moc a class. So I would say impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Boost's signal slot mechanism. [Boost Signal Slot](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/signals.html)

And if you are using Qt 4.1 or greater both can be used together as explained here [Boost signals & slots with Qt](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2007/06/15/boost-signals-slots-with-qt/)